# Sort arraylist that contains subclass classes

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

i have an ArrayList that contains Fruits.

I also have a subclass of Fruits called "Apples".

Apples have a "Color" attribute that the other Fruits subclasses don't have.

How can i sort this list? (I have to put only the "Apple" objects in another list.)

Fruits is the parent class, Apple and the others are subclasses.

Comment: How do you want to sort them?

Comment: @Crozin I want to have an arraylist only with Apple objects

Comment: Nit: if you have a class, it should be capitalized.  If you have an instance of that class, lowercase.  So you have an ArrayList fruits, and a subclass Apples, by common Java style.

Comment: Unless it's an ArrayList containing objects of the class Fruits.

Comment: @DeanJ The arraylist is type Fruits but it contains apples, pinnaples and others

Comment: duplicate -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675827/java-sorting-out-subclass-from-arraylist-of-superclass?rq=1

Comment: why you need to sort fruits?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker Fruits was an example, the real case is with agents of a callcenter, there are Agents, Agent-Senior and Agent-Junior (both of them extends Agent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `instanceof` will be one way of doing that.

```
Fruits[] myFruits = ...... // Array of fruits
for (int i = 0; i < myFruits.length; i++) {
    if (myFruits[i] instanceof Apple) {
        // ...
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
java.util.Collections.sort(listOfFruits,(fruit1,fruit2) -> /*implementation of your order relation between Fruits*/ 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions:

1. Implement

   `Comparator<Fruit>`

But this will require comparing Fruits only, so your Fruit class would have to have all necessary for comparison attributes. Or you could use instanceOf inside of it, this should let you cast safely.

```
new Comparator<Fruit>{
      @Overwrite
      public int compare(Fruit a1, Fruita 2) {
         if(a1 instanceOf Apple.class) {...}
         else if ( ... ){}
         ...
      }

    }
```

2. Have your `Fruits` implement `Comparable` interface. That way each of them will have their own logic, but this aproach is less advisable - tight coupling.

My solution:

If you are interested in obtaining apples only, you can split your array into two (Apples and non-apples) and sort only apples, using `Comparator<Apple>`.

```
List<Apples> apples = fruits.filter(m -> m.getClass()== Apple.class).collect(Collectors.toList());
Collections.sort(apples, new Comparator<Apple>{
  @Overwrite
  public int compare(Apple a1, Apple a2) {

  }

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You should implements the [comparable class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) in your `Fruit` by either using `instanceof` or by having the specific implementation for each subclass.

ie:

```
public class Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit> {
    String fruitName;

    public int compareTo(Fruit other){
        // compareTo should return < 0 if this is supposed to be
        // less than other, > 0 if this is supposed to be greater than 
        // other and 0 if they are supposed to be equal
        if (fruitName == null) {
            if (other.fruitName == null) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        } else {
            if (other.fruitName == null) {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        return fruitName.compareTo(other.fruitName);
    }
}
```

Another option would be defining a [comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for example:

```
public class MyFruitcomparator implements Comparator<Fruit> {
   public int compare(Fruit obj1, Fruit obj2) {
      //your logic here, below just an example
      return obj1.getFruitName().compareTo(obj2.getFruitName());
   }
}
```

In the examples above I used `fruitName` just as an example but the actual implementation depends on your needs.